# How to prevent default event firing but still allow event to bubble

Tags: jquery, events, click, event-bubbling

Using jQuery: with the following code I'd like to prevent the href url (in this case a hash '#') being fired on click, but still allow the click event to continue bubbling up the chain. How can this be achieved please?

```
<div>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
</div>

$('a').click(function(e){
    // stop a.click firing but allow click event to continue bubbling?
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // stop a.click firing but allow click event to continue bubbling?
});
```

`e.preventDefault()` won't prevent bubbling, `e.stopPropagation()` or `return false` (stop both) will.

Comment: The point is that it needs to bubble, just not run the default process.

Comment: Which is exactly what `e.preventDefault();` will do. I dropped in the extra bits so the OP would know the next time such an issue will arise.

Comment: @Shef Thanks Shef and to everyone else. I've been using e.preventDefault() in combination with 'return false' for some time now, but have never had to utilise the benefits of event delegation before, which is why this query arose.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    // stop a.click firing but allow click event to continue bubbling?

});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tU53v/

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$('a').click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    // stop a.click firing but allow click event to continue bubbling?

});
```

[**here**](http://css-tricks.com/6809-return-false-and-prevent-default/) you can find difference between `return false` and `e.preventDefault();`