# How to prevent default link action and still allow bubbling?

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, event-bubbling

After reading this question [How to prevent default event firing but still allow event to bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745618/how-to-prevent-default-event-firing-but-still-allow-event-to-bubble), I am still having the issue where the event is not prevented and when the link is clicked, it takes the user to the top of the page.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="ajax-load"><a href="/?show=all" id="set-home">HOME</a></div>

   <div id="preContent">
       <div id="content">
           //SOME CONTENT
       </div>
   </div>
```

My jQuery is:

```
jQuery('.ajax-load').click(function() { 
   //DO SOME STUFF
   //LOADS SOME URL INSIDE A DIV
   return false;

});

jQuery('#set-home').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();  
   //DO SOME STUFF  
   //SETS SOME NEW ATTRIBUTES FOR ANOTHER ELEMENT       
});
```

I need to prevent default behavior for both parent and child and allow bubbling.

### EDIT: (to clarify what I am trying to do...)

When I click `#set-home`, I am changing an attribute in another element and at the same time, `.ajax-load` will fire a function that loads and url in an element.

### EDIT 2:

This is the code I have for `.ajax-load`

```
var mainContent = jQuery("#preContent"),
    is_ajaxed_page  = "",
    everPushed  = false,    

jQuery(".ajax-load").on("click infinite", "a", function() {
    _link = jQuery(this).attr("href");
    history.pushState(null, null, _link);
    everPushed = true;
    jQuery(mainContent).waypoint("destroy");
    loadContent(_link);
    return false;
});

function loadContent(href){
    jQuery(mainContent)
            .find("#content")
            .fadeOut(100, function() {
                jQuery(mainContent).hide().load(href + " #content", { is_ajaxed_page: "yes" }, function() {
                    jQuery(mainContent).fadeIn(100, function() {
                        infscroll();

                    });         
                });
            });

}
```

Comment: `preventDefault()` prevents default action but not bubling.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` does exactly what you want. Can you verify that you've attached the `.click()` event to that anchor element?

Comment: are you sure ? @WereWolf-TheAlpha
he is not talking about event bubling concept.
he is just telling that page kicks back to the top on click of the event which happens when we hash value

Comment: What exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: `preventDefault()` prevents default action, in this case it won't let the link navigate but still it lets bubling, I think there is an error so `preventDefault/js` is not working, check browser's console.

Comment: Did you use `$(document).ready(...)` ?

Comment: Unless i'm mis-understanding what you are trying to do, your code should work correctly. Clicking the link will change attributes etc and then bubble, causing the ajax request, but it will not change the page url. It will stop bubbling at `.ajax-load`

Comment: Perhaps you can better clarify the issue. Is it that when you click #set-home you don't want the click on  .ajax-load also triggered or are you saying that the browser is still following the link (and you don't want it to)?

Comment: be clear with your question. show the complete code where you are doing the setting attr and stuff.

Comment: @KevinB yes, that is what I want it to do, but somehow I must be missing something and it is not preventing the default behavior. I edited my question to clarify what I am trying to do.

Comment: actually its working fine for me. you just forgot to put document.ready i feel

Comment: @susheel I do have document.ready. I tried removing `.ajax-load` from the link and the default event is prevented. So the problem must be inside `.ajax-load` I edited my question to include it.

Comment: `jQuery(mainContent).waypoint("destroy");` where are you declaring mainContent ??

Comment: @susheel just above the event, `mainContent = jQuery("#preContent"),` However `#preContent` is below `#set-home` in my HTML

Comment: can I know your requirement. is it similar to facebook content load on scrolling ??

Comment: @susheel yes, I am using the waypoints + infinite plugin to load new content https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints Everytime I load a new page, I have to destroy it and create a new instance of the plugin.

Comment: try this [scrollpagination](http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/) link

Comment: @susheel thanks for the tip but I like the plugin I am using better.